# Reliable way to find out which ruby to use in shebang

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, shebang

I wrote a script `todo.rb`, whose first line is `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. However, running this script gives the following error:

```
λ ~/ ruby todo/todo.rb 
/Users/xjia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- highline/import (LoadError)
    from /Users/xjia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from todo/todo.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I have already installed the gem `highline`:

```
λ ~/ which gem
/Users/xjia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/gem
λ ~/ gem install highline
Successfully installed highline-1.6.15
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for highline-1.6.15...
Installing RDoc documentation for highline-1.6.15...
λ ~/ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/xjia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/xjia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/xjia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/xjia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
     - /Users/xjia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

and I can `require` it in `irb`:

```
λ ~/ which irb
/Users/xjia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb
λ ~/ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'highline/import'
=> true
```

However, `require` in `ruby` fails exactly the same:

```
λ ~/ which ruby
ruby: aliased to bundled_ruby
λ ~/ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
λ ~/ ruby -e "require 'highline/import'"
/Users/xjia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- highline/import (LoadError)
    from /Users/xjia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm using [rvm](https://rvm.io) under both Ubuntu and Mac OS X. From my Ubuntu box, this shebang line works fine. However, it sucks under OS X. So what's the reliable way to find out the usable `ruby`?

Comment: Which version of OSX are you running?

Comment: @ply 10.7.5 (it's a Macbook Air)

Comment: The few times I've ran into this or a similar error its been due to the script not being executable. Have you tried chmod +x todo.rb?

Comment: This isn't an issue with your shebang obviously (One easy way to debug ruby shebang is to run `#!/usr/bin/env ruby;puts RUBY_VERSION`). This is a gem problem. Please attach output of `gem environment`.

Comment: @ply Of course, I can use it under Ubuntu.

Comment: @quandrum `puts RUBY_VERSION` shows `1.9.3`. I also updated my question with the output of `gem environment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> `λ ~/ which ruby`
>   `ruby: aliased to bundled_ruby`

you need to check:

```
which bundled_ruby
```

and make sure it also has proper shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

finally removing the alias for ruby should solve the problem, you might want check my gem `rubygems-bundler` which is by default installed with RVM - it provides more "intelligent" means of detecting and using bundler.

Comment: `which bundled_ruby` shows `bundled_ruby () {
 _run-with-bundler ruby $@
}`. Not sure if it's OK?

Comment: `which bundle` shows `/Users/xjia/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/bundle`

Comment: no it is not ok, you need to `which  _run-with-bundler` ... and continue to which till you find what is used really.

Comment: It's `_run-with-bundler () {
 if _bundler-installed && _within-bundled-project
 then
  bundle exec $@
 else
  $@
 fi
}` so I ran `which bundle`

Comment: just remove the alias, it's running `ruby bundle exec ruby ...` which is double slow

Comment: Isn't the alias created by rvm?

Comment: I finally got the issue. I switched to zsh some time ago and forgot to add `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function` to my `.zshrc`

Comment: anyway you should remove the `alias` for `ruby` it makes all calls to ruby slow and is obsolete as `rubygems-bundler` gives you better bundler detection.